# Spring-data-cassandra: Passing an enum array value as parameter in @Query statement fails

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, reactive-programming, spring-data-cassandra

In a spring boot 2.3.1 application which utilises spring-data-cassandra, I have an enum property **leadType** in primary key.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table("leads_by_date_and_type")
public class LeadByDateTypeOrigin {

    @PrimaryKey
    private LeadDateTypeOriginKey primaryKey;

    @Column("lead_identifier")
    @Indexed("leads_identifier")
    private Long leadIdentifier;

}


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@PrimaryKeyClass
public class LeadDateTypeOriginKey implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "created_date", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private LocalDate createdDate;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "type", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    @Indexed("leads_type")
    @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
    private LeadType leadType;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "origin", ordinal = 0, ordering = Ordering.ASCENDING)
    @Indexed("leads_origin")
    private String origin;

    public LeadDateTypeOriginKey(XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar, LeadType leadType, String origin) {
        this.createdDate = LocalDate.of(xmlGregorianCalendar.getYear(), xmlGregorianCalendar.getMonth(), xmlGregorianCalendar.getDay());
        this.leadType = leadType;
        this.origin = origin;
    }
}
```

I've added an accompanying converter

```
@ReadingConverter
public enum LeadTypeConverter implements Converter<LeadType, String> {
    INSTANCE;
    @Override
    public String convert(LeadType leadType) {
        return leadType.name();
    }
}
```

and registered the custom converter in the configuration class as shown below

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class CassandraConfiguration extends AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration {

@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
private String keySpaceName;

@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter}")
private String localDataCentre;

@Override
protected String getKeyspaceName() {
    return keySpaceName;
}

@Override
protected String getLocalDataCenter() {
    return localDataCentre;
}

@Override
public CassandraCustomConversions customConversions() {
    return new CassandraCustomConversions(
            Arrays.asList(LeadTypeConverter.INSTANCE)
    );
}
```

}

When I try and execute the query method **findBy(lead)**,

```
@Repository
public interface LeadRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<LeadByDateTypeOrigin, LeadDateTypeOriginKey> {

    default Mono<LeadByDateTypeOrigin> findBy(@NonNull final LocalDate createdDate,
                                              @NonNull final LeadType leadType,
                                              @NonNull final String origin) {
        return findById(new LeadDateTypeOriginKey(createdDate, leadType, origin));
    }

        @Query("SELECT * FROM leads_by_date_and_type WHERE created_date <= toDate(now()) AND type IN (?0) ALLOW FILTERING")
    Flux<LeadByDateTypeOrigin> findBy(@NonNull final LeadType... leadType);

}
```

I get the following error

com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.type.codec.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [null <-> [Lcom.example.application.domain.LeadType;]

```
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.createCodec(CachingCodecRegistry.java:639)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.createCodec(CachingCodecRegistry.java:558)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry$1.load(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:95)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry$1.load(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:92)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3527)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2276)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3973)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4957)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.shaded.guava.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4963)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.DefaultCodecRegistry.getCachedCodec(DefaultCodecRegistry.java:117)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.type.codec.registry.CachingCodecRegistry.codecFor(CachingCodecRegistry.java:287)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.Conversions.encode(Conversions.java:304)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.Conversions.encode(Conversions.java:263)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.Conversions.toMessage(Conversions.java:168)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestHandler.<init>(CqlRequestHandler.java:173)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.java:44)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestAsyncProcessor.java:29)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:230)
at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.AsyncCqlSession.executeAsync(AsyncCqlSession.java:41)
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.session.DefaultBridgedReactiveSession.lambda$execute$0(DefaultBridgedReactiveSession.java:150)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$fromCompletionStage$0(Mono.java:430)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8325)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:199)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMapMany.java:49)
at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8311)
at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.blockFirst(Flux.java:2474)
```

Apparently, the issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-521 was fixed a while ago but it seems to work only for non-array parameters. Is it a spring-data-cassandra bug or limitation?

Comment: Can you file a ticket at jira.spring.io? Considering array types would make a lot of sense.